# Modifing jQuery validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How can I change the jQuery validation message based on logic used when validating?  My attempt is shown below, however, `this.extra` shows up as being undefined.

```
$.validator.addMethod("someMethod", function(value, element, params) {
    //Logic to validate and determine message goes here...
    var valid=false;
    this.extra="bla";
    return valid;
    }, $.validator.format("message plus "+this.extra)
);
```

Comment: isn't this.extra outside the scope of `$.validator.format("message plus "+this.extra)` as it is being called from inside the function? can you call `$.validator.format("message plus "+this.extra)` inside the function?

Comment: @DerekPollard.  It appears it is outside of scope.  I "can" call it inside the function, but need to pass it as the 3rd parameter to `addMethod()`.

Comment: What if you set a global variable outside of this alltogether, then once the function is ran, set the global variable to the `this.extra` value then in the `$.validator.format("message plus "+this.extra)` portion, change it to this: `$.validator.format("message plus "+globalVariable)`

Comment: Do it by turning the 3rd parameter into a function.

Comment: @Sparky  Please look at the answer which you indicated answers the question, and verify whether it is accurate.  As far as I could tell, it is not as `element` is not a jQuery object, and doesn't support `data()`.  The part about turning the 3rd parameter into a function, however, is the key part, and does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but it's bit tricky. You need to [set attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) or use [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate your information with element.

```
$.validator.addMethod("someMethod", function(value, element, params) {
    //Logic to validate and determine message goes here...
    var valid=false;
    $(element).data('extra', "bla");
    return valid;
    }, function(params, element) {
      return $.validator.format("message plus " + $(element).data('extra'))
    }
);
```

Comment: `element` is not a jQuery object, and both this answer the the answer to the question I duplicated doesn't work.

Comment: then you can use `$(element)`. or `element.setAttribute`